# how to fail groovy script via assert, if xml node is not present in Switch statement

Tags: xml, groovy, switch-statement, soapui

This is my script,

```
import groovy.xml.*

def xml = '''<ROOT>
<Profile>12</Profile>
<Rate>3072</Rate>
<AudioRate>0</AudioRate>
<GPS>15</GPS>
</ROOT>'''

def Xmlnodes = new XmlParser().parseText(xml)

Xmlnodes.each { setting -> 

switch (setting.name()) {
    case 'Profile': break;
    case 'Rate': break;
    case 'GPS': break;
    default: log.info "Unknown Unit Config Element: " + setting.name()
          }   
}
```

How can I fail this script as AudioRate node is not present in switch statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to validate that your *XML* contains at least one `<AudioRate/>` element, it's not necessary to do so inside  the `switch`.

You can add an `assert` to check if at least one `<AudioRate/>` element exists in your *XML* as follows:

```java
assert Xmlnodes.'**'.findAll { it.name() == 'AudioRate' }.size() > 0
```

If you've a list of required node names you can use the follow code to make fail your test if some of these names are not present in the *XML*:

```java
// required node names
['Profile','Rate','AudioRate','GPS'].each { nodeName ->
    assert Xmlnodes.'**'.findAll { it.name() == nodeName }.size() > 0
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I think that I misunderstood your requeriment, and instead of check that your *XML* has at least all required elements you are looking for a check to validate that *XML* only contains allowed elements. If this is the case you can do it using your `switch` by simply adding an `assert false` in your `default`.

```java
Xmlnodes.each { setting ->
  switch (setting.name()) {
    case 'Profile': break;
    case 'Rate': break;
    case 'GPS': break;
    default: 
         log.info "Unknown Unit Config Element: " + setting.name()
         assert false
  }   
}
```

Or in a more *Groovy* way, checking that all *XML* node names are in allowed list:

```java
assert ['Profile','Rate','GPS'].containsAll(Xmlnodes*.name())​
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Based on your comments from the chat, if you want to check first if all child node names of `<Screen>` (in case that at least on exists) are in allowed list and then perform the check for allowed names in the `<ROOT>` node, you can do something like:

```java
def xml = '''<ROOT> 
    <Profile>12</Profile> 
    <Rate>3072</Rate> 
    <AudioRate>0</AudioRate> 
    <GPS>15</GPS> 
    <Screen> 
        <Video>12</Video> 
        <Rate>600</Rate> 
        <Camera>1</Camera> 
    </Screen> 
    <Screen> 
        <Devices> 
            <audioDevice>1</audioDevice> 
        </Devices> 
    </Screen>
</ROOT>'''

def Xmlnodes = new XmlParser().parseText(xml)

// <Screen> nodes exists...
if(Xmlnodes.Screen){
    // [Video, Rate, Camera, Devices] --> [Video,Rate,Camera] are from first <Screen> [Devices] are from the second <Screen>
    println Xmlnodes.Screen*.collect { it.name() }.sum() 

    // get all childnode names for all the possible <Screen> elements in one list and
    // check that all names are allowed
    assert ['Video', 'Rate', 'Camera', 'Devices'].containsAll(Xmlnodes.Screen*.collect { it.name() }.sum() )
}

// check that only allowed names are in xml
assert ['Profile','Rate','GPS','AudioRate','Screen'].containsAll(Xmlnodes*.name())
```

**UPDATE 3:**

Since in your last comment, you told that you want to know also the name of the unknown tags on the *XML*, then you can perform a `-` operations from your predefined list of node names, this way the rest are the unknown elements; this is my last attempt:

```java
def Xmlnodes = new XmlParser().parseText(xml)

def screenUnknown = []

// <Screen> nodes exists...
if(Xmlnodes.Screen){
    // get all unknown elements
    screenUnknown = Xmlnodes.Screen*.collect { it.name() }.sum() - ['Video', 'Rate', 'Camera', 'Devices']
}

// get all unknown nodes in root
def rootUnknown = Xmlnodes*.name() -  ['Profile','Rate','GPS','AudioRate','Screen']

println "unknown in <Root>: ${rootUnknown}"
println "unknown in <Screen>: ${screenUnknown}"

// optionally you can make an assert to check
// that there aren't unknown elements
assert rootUnknown.size() == 0, 'THE ARE UNKNOWN ELEMENTS IN <ROOT>'
assert screenUnknown.size()  == 0,  'THE ARE UNKNOWN ELEMENTS IN <SCREEN>'
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thanks @albciff, but I don't want to hardcode node value in assert, as I don't know which unknown node will come in my rest api response, here i just provide an example.

Comment: @Geeta I misunderstood your question. So the thing is that you want to check that all required nodes are present? Do you know all required node names?

Comment: Thank you so much @albciff, but if assert fail once it will not let switch statement to continue , so I added assert after my switch statement, but it fails even if all the nodes are present :(

Comment: @Getta sorry I don't understand what do you exactly want. Do you want to check that the XML only contains a set of defined nodes and fail if some different node name is present... or do you want to check that all defined nodes must exists but you don't care if there are others?

Comment: Actually i want to check my xml schema and yes I know all  the nodes name :)

Comment: Yes I want to check that the XML only contains a set of defined nodes and fail if some different node name is present

Comment: @Geeta then this `assert ['Profile','Rate','GPS'].containsAll(Xmlnodes*.name())​` must works, since it checks that all your node names are inside the list... if not it return false

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122485/discussion-between-geeta-and-albciff).

Comment: Thanks @albciff, but i want to print ALL unknown elements too, I'm using this code but it is not provide me all unknown element , as assert stops further execution if fails, 
Xmlnodes.Screen*.collect {
 assert it.name() in [ 'Rate', 'Camera'] : "Unknown Unit Config Element: ${it.name()}" }

}

Comment: @Getta I update my answer with your last requeriment, this is my last attempt. Please the next time try to explain better your requirements in the question, since you simply wrote *How can I fail this script as AudioRate node is not present in switch statement* but the final question differs a lot from this phrase.

Comment: Thank you so much @albciff :) , exactly what i wanted, yes i will take care of this next time sure :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
...
def Xmlnodes = new XmlParser().parseText(xml)

Xmlnodes.each { setting -> 
    assert setting.name() in ['Profile','Rate','GPS'] : "Unknown Unit Config Element: ${setting.name()}"
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @BalRog, Excellent :) . But I want to do it using switch statement as conditions will be added in cases : (